# Running total for certain rows in SAS

Tags: sas

[image]

[A small sample of the data can be downloaded from my Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rxqMvUtVRuWWG7FjXgJUyXx62vEz35db/view?usp=drive_link)

You can use the data to debug my code.

This is how my data looks like. At each annual report date, there is a count of male directors (male_dirs) and a count of female directors (male_dirs).

During a year, members may leave or join the board, denoted by male_dirs_ann and female_dirs_ann ("_ann" is for "announcement" because they are merged from the "announcement" table), where 1 indicates one joined, -1 one left.

I wanted to update the numbers of male and female directors (male_dirs and female_dirs) when any left or joined the board, by generating two new variables, "total_male" and "total_female". On the annual report dates, I just copied over the male_dirs and female_dirs because there is no change on these date. For dates with changes, I took the number from the last date (male_dirs/female_dirs) and added/deducted the current change (male_dirs_ann/female_dirs_ann).

Row 2: total_male = 7 + 1 = 8, which is correct.

**Row 6 is wrong: A male director left, and total_male should have been 6 (i.e., 7-1).**
Rows 9 and 17 are also wrong, among others.

My code is as follows:

```
data board_size_change;
set board_size_change;
by companyID date;
retain total_male total_female;

if first.companyID = 1 then do; 
   total_male = 0;
   total_female = 0;
end;

*At annual report date;
if not missing(annualreportdate) then do;
    total_male=male_dirs;
    total_female=female_dirs;
    output;
end;

*At announcement;
if missing(annualreportdate) then do;
    total_male + male_dirs_ann;
    total_female + female_dirs_ann;
    output;
end;
run;
```

What I missed or is there another way to approach this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: While programming, this might be better asked over on the "[statistics.se]" site, which is the stackexchange for statistics (including SAS questions).

Comment: Cannot code from photographs of data.

Comment: I uploaded a small sample of the data

Comment: I've tried this using your code and can only produce the same results as you if I update your row 6 male_dirs_ann value to have a 'funny' dash in front that prevents it being interpreted as minus-1. Can you check if the data has been corrupted by a copy-paste or anything?

Comment: No copy-paste was involved. The data has been manipulated/generated using code.  The negative numbers were generated by using the following code:  if will_leave=1 then do;
male_dirs_ann = male_dirs_ann * (-1);
female_dirs_ann = female_dirs_ann * (-1);
end;

Comment: Finally found out that there wasn't any issue with the code. The error was due to a later data step where I merged in a variable from another dataset, and this messed up the output.